# Why does my connection to cloud sql from local php app engine development fail using ipv6?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, mysqli, google-cloud-sql

So I want to connect to a google cloud sql instance using it's free ipv6 adress instead of buying an ipv4 address. For that I looked ip my ipv6 address and allowed it. I also looked up my routers ipv6 prefix and allowed that (afaik that should allow all pc in my home network to access the sql instance).

The following code creates the problem:

```
$servername = "2001:6532:1234:1:6a4f:e1d7:5d69:52a3";
$username = "looooool";
$password = "superSecretStuff";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

And that code generates this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt. in C:\Users\kjh\Documents\SF WEBSITE\appengine-try-php-master\connect_db.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt. in C:\Users\kjh\Documents\SF WEBSITE\appengine-try-php-master\connect_db.php on line 8
Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt.
```

I'm sorry that the error message is in german, but I don't know where I would even change that. Also line 8 is the line with `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` on it. I've changed the ip adress so if it looks wierd that is why. Hope you can help me.

Ninja edit: If I get an IPv4 adress from google it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I theory the answer is just to change `$servername = "2001:6532:1234:1:6a4f:e1d7:5d69:52a3";` to `$servername = "[2001:6532:1234:1:6a4f:e1d7:5d69:52a3]";` that is if your network or ISP is not doing something crazy with your IPv6 address as mine is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some ISP (internet service providers), especially ones focused on residential customers, are very cavalier with the assignment and persistence of IPv6 addresses and ranges to their customers -- while, with IPv4, it's easier to know where one stands (there's typically an optional fee to pay for a persistent, static IPv4 address -- if you don't pay that fee, then by default you get a dynamic IPv4 address and you know that *is* liable to change at any time). I have verified that misbehavior by using several services such as whatismyip.com and the like. As a result, I can't reliably use Cloud SQL from my home network (which goes through AT&T) while I have no problem at the office (static IP addresses, either v4 or v6 both work fine).

You may want to ask the question again on serverfault, since it is entirely about network administration, not at all about software development (nor, particularly, about Cloud SQL) -- with all details about what ISPs are available to you, and focusing on "how to get predictable, non-fluidly-changing IPv6 externally visible addresses" w/the given ISPs (with AT&T, I've given up on that quest, at least for now).

Comment: I live in germany and have Kabel Deutschland as an ISP and for some reason my ipv4 only changes when I restart my router, so it is kind of persistent. At least enough to set it up and be abel to use it the same day right after I've set it up. And that works when I'm using and IPv4 adrress. So why should it not work with and IPv6 address? Also should the code above work and there is just a networking fault? Or is there a diffrent syntax for IPv6 connections with mysqli?